# Lotusscript NotesHTTPRequest Issue

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I'm trying to use the new Rest features in LotusScript (Notes Client Release 10.0.1) to retrieve address information from Google. Unfortunately, I get an error when trying to get a response. If I try the same url in the browser, I get no errors. There is no proxy configured.

Here's some sample code

```
Dim Session As New NotesSession        
Dim ret As String
Dim URL As String
Dim headers As Variant
Dim webRequest As NotesHTTPRequest
Set webRequest = session.createhttprequest()

url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Antwerp&<my Google API key>"

ret  = webrequest.Get(URL)
```

When I run this code in an agent, I get the following error on the last line:

> Type mismatch in method CoerceString: Unknown found, Unknown expected

Comment: Strange: the code works for me here.. but documentation sais, that return value should be a variant: `Return value
Variant

Returns Variant content which contains JSON string.`

Comment: Hi Torsten. Using a Variant works. However, it does not return a JSON string, but a byte array. Converting the array to a string gives me the JSON I require.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/10.0.1/basic/H_GET_METHOD.html) for that command states:

> **Return value**
> Variant
>
> Returns Variant content which contains JSON string.

And the error message that you get is typical for getting a variant and trying to cast it to a string.

The strange thing: With some websites it seams to work (probably depending of the type of data the website returns) with

```
Dim ret as String
```

Although the documentation is wrong in stating that the variant contains a JSON string (indeed it simply contains whatever the called website returns, that might be a JSON string, but can simply be the source code of the website as well), it still is right, that one should expect a variant as return value.

So this line should work:

```
Dim ret as Variant
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little late to the party here but I thought I would add that the simple solution is to set:

```
webRequest.Preferstrings = True
```

Then you will get a string back from the call ;-)

Comment: Unless the webserver returns NULL terminated strings. Then you will need to read the byte array and create a string.