# LotusScript NotesHTTPRequest Get Method Issue

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I am trying to access an API using the REST feature. But I can't retrieve the data.

Here the code

```
Dim Session As New NotesSession        
Dim ret As Variant
Dim URL As String
Dim headers As Variant
Dim webRequest As NotesHTTPRequest
Set webRequest = session.createhttprequest()

URL = "https://www.meteoblue.com/en/server/search/query3?query=basel"

ret  = webrequest.Get(URL)

Messagebox ret
```

I already solved my previous problem with this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54073170/lotusscript-noteshttprequest-issue), but I have another error now. When I run this code, I get the following error (The problem is with "ret"):

> Type mismatch in method OP_CHECK_TOS_BYVAL : BYTE found, Unknown expected

Does anyone have any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lotusscript NotesHTTPRequest Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54073170/lotusscript-noteshttprequest-issue)

Comment: Error handler? Please add an error handler to see the LINE where this error occurs... This line `Messagebox ret` -e.g.- cannot work because Messagebox expects a string and not a variant...

Comment: ask HCL for why they decided to go with that implementation, I have no idea...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I repeat myself like a broken record: Add error handler to EVERY LINE OF CODE.

In your example you have exactly 4 lines of code where something can go wrong. And nevertheless you can't find out, which of the 4 lines causes the error if you don't use error handling (of course you could by using the debugger, but this is another story...).

Without an error handler I can only guess, that your error comes from this line:

```
Messagebox ret
```

ret is defined as Variant and the [help of the function](https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/10.0.1/basic/H_GET_METHOD.html) tells you, that it will return a byte array:

> **Return value**
> Variant
>
> Returns Variant content as **JSON UTF8 byte array**. Use the preferstrings property to return Unicode rather than UTF8 byte array.

But Messagebox expects a String as parameter --> Type mismatch...